# Defined constant inside PLAIN TEXT message

Tags: php

I am sending an email with a pre-defined signature

```
define('Signature', 'Our Great Support Team');
```

so email body looks like this:

```
$msg = 'Hails folks. <br />Thanks for your time, blah-blah <br />'.Signature.';
```

works well.. but it has to be sent as a PLAIN TEXT

```
$msg = "Hails folks\nThanks for your time, blah-blah\nSignature";
```

obviously - that won't work.
this could be solved by adding a variable:

```
$signature = Signature; 
$msg = "Hails folks\nThanks for your time, blah-blah\n$signature";
```

this will work but can it be done easier? Something like:

```
 $msg = "Hails folks\nThanks for your time, blah-blah\nconstant('Signature')";
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: the defined constant in plain text will be sent as a plain text. Example: instead of Signature = ''Our Great Support Team" it will be sent as "Signature"

Comment: Does that `define()` constant file included in the file from where you are sending email?

Comment: Of course `$msg = "Hails folks\nThanks for your time, blah-blah\nSignature";` will works. And `Signature` will display as plain `Signature`. Whats your problem?

Comment: Thruout the site I am using several constants. such as Sitename, Site_email, Site_url etc

whe I am sending an email IN PLAIN TEXT - I cannot use pre-defined constants because instead of their values they will be simply rendered as a text

Comment: I need something like this:

$msg = "Hails there\n\nSIGNATURE"; 
that will be sent as "Hails there
Your great support guys"
because "Signature" is a constant

Comment: `define('Signature', 'Our Great Support Team'); echo $msg = 'Hails folks. <br />Thanks for your time, blah-blah <br />'.Signature;`, This is wprking for me, what error you get?

Comment: I have mentioned that this WORKS, Kausha
I need it in PLAIN:
$msg = "Hails folks\nThanks for your time, blah-blah\nSignature";

Comment: @Rossitten What's the difference between using `sprintf` and plain text? they both just return a string and can be used anywhere in place of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using sprintf function

```
define('Signature', 'Our Great Support Team');
$msg = sprintf('Hails folks. <br />Thanks for your time, blah-blah <br /> %s', Signature);
```